Tag purpose: optimization
The optimization was created in only in July of this year and has no usage guidance or tag wiki.  It has seven questions, most of which are about the colloquial use of the term ‘optimization’ to mean ‘making something faster’, and one of which is about the technical use of the term to mean ‘finding parameters that minimize/maximize some objective function subject to constraints’.
Does this tag serve any useful categorization purpose for Crypto.SE?  Should we delete it?

We should delete the optimization tag because it serves no useful categorization purpose.

We should keep the optimization tag because…
Fill in a reason, Community!
